# WinAPI Documentation contradicting itself?

Tags: c, winapi

So I've just been looking through the Windows Documentation just to read up on some stuff and to get a broader understanding as to how the WinAPI works and so on, however, I couldn't help but notice the fact that the documentation seems to contradict itself in some cases and I need some reassurance as to which way of doing things is *really* the correct way of doing things. The specific example I'm looking at deals with the GetMessage() function and the 'Window Message Loop'.

The first site ([Window Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/window-messages)) states that the correct syntax for the message loop is the following...

```
MSG msg = { };
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

(if you scroll down it's right before the '**Posted Messages versus Sent Messages**' heading near the bottom of the page)

The doc explains that the WM_QUIT message causes the function to return 0 which in turn will lead to the while loop breaking and the application terminating. Otherwise, the function will return a non-zero value causing the while loop to continue.

The second site ([The one for the GetMessage() function)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage) explicitly states to avoid writing code like the one previously explained. This site says that the GetMessage() function can return a value of -1 in case of an error and that using code like this

```
while (GetMessage( lpMsg, hWnd, 0, 0)) ...
```

would cause the application to continue running if the function returns -1 even though it should handle the error and terminate appropriately. The valid implementation for the message loop should then be this...

```
BOOL bRet;

while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, hWnd, 0, 0 )) != 0)
{ 
    if (bRet == -1)
    {
        // handle the error and possibly exit
    }
    else
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }
}
```

I have always done it this way so that I could catch the -1 error if there happens to be one. But after seeing Microsoft basically make the supposed mistake themselves now I am confused. So which is it Microsoft? Is it valid or not valid to do this?

```
MSG msg = { };
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're using the correct version.

Comment: See [When will GetMessage return -1?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130322-00/?p=4873) on MSDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not comparing like with like. The documentation states that `-1` is returned if `hWnd` is invalid.

In the first case the loop is passing `NULL`

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
```

and so `-1` cannot be returned. But in the second example

```
while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, hWnd, 0, 0 )) != 0)
```

the variable `hWnd` is being passed so there can be an error.

Comment: Well, for what I understand passing an invalid hWnd into the GetMessage would be an _example_ of an error, however, [this tutorial](http://winprog.org/tutorial/message_loop.html) clearly states that it can still return -1.

Comment: Can also return `-1` if the message pointer is invalid, but if it is the program is broken anyway. I think the earlier documentation has been improved, and, in such a huge documentation resource there are probably other inconsistencies too. Anyway I love the way that Window's `BOOL` can have 3 values :)

Comment: I suppose that makes sense then. Would you recommend still checking for that -1 though? Even though your passing in NULL it just seems safer to check for that in case anything bad happens ;D

Comment: Yes, I guess it would make sense to be more rigorous. Then if it happens you can try to fail gracefully even if you can't recover.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan as OP points out, there are other reasons for `-1` to be returned. It's probably more useful in development than in release versions.

Comment: @weather There really aren't any other possible reasons. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130322-00/?p=4873

Comment: @DavidHeffernan as your link says: "or `lpMsg` is an invalid pointer". All this has been covered in the answer and in comments.

Comment: @weather the pointer is clearly valid, no point over complicating the message loop here.

Comment: If you are passing an invalid pointer for *lpMsg*, you have entered undefined behavior territory already. There's no point in guarding against possible outcomes of undefined behavior. There's really only a single way to deal with undefined behavior: Don't write code that exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @IInspectable that's true, and I already commented "Can also return -1 if the message pointer is invalid, but if it is the program is broken anyway." The answer was addressing the question of why the treatments are different. I also pointed out that it could be useful to catch the fault during the development phase.

Comment: I'm going to argue, that it isn't even useful during development. `GetMessage` only returns `-1` for *some* invalid pointers (like a `nullptr`), but not for others (like a pointer pointing into some random stack location). There's way too little return on investment here, particularly since `GetMessage` cannot fail, when used in a reasonable way: Don't filter on a window handle, and pass a pointer to an object with automatic storage duration.